# Connecting to SQL Server Express database over ad hoc wireless network

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-express, ad-hoc-network

I have a laptop that has a SQL Server Express database on it.  By Using `sqlcmd` below on this laptop I can access this database and run queries against the tables easily:

```
sqlcmd -S Jarvis\SQLExpress
```

I set the laptop up as an ad hoc wireless network (I called the network "MyNetwork").  My other laptops can connect to the ad hoc network without issue.

The problem I'm having is this:

When trying to use `sqlcmd` below to connect to the database from one of the connected laptops, I can never connect.  Here's the command that I'm using:

```
sqlcmd -S Jarvis\SQLExpress
```

I've also tried using the IP address of the laptop that is hosting the ad hoc network and database:

```
sqlcmd -S 169.254.104.85\Jarvis\SQLExpress
```

The error that I'm getting seems to indicate that the login timeout expired.  The error that I'm getting is like the second error message in the image below (I grabbed this image from the web, this is not my actual error):

[image: SQL Error]

So, even though I can connect the laptop to the ad hoc network, it doesn't appear to be able to "see" the SQL Server Express database.  I've never attempted something like this, so I'm sure I've missed a step along the way.  Is there an option or something that I should take to make the database visible to all laptops that are connected to the ad hoc network?

Comment: there are two main ways to authenticate to SQL Server, one is using active directory name (windows logins) the other is SQL Server Logins, in you scenario you want SQL Server logins so you may have to create a new one, or just use the SA which is the GOD account. Second you need to enable TCP/IP if it has not been enabled, when you set that up also check what port your instance is on. Lastly save yourself some trouble and use a SQL Client to connect. SQLCMD is only useful in emergencies.

Comment: @M.Scherzer Ah!  That makes sense.  If I understand you correctly, I just need to provide the SA (Server Agent) logon credentials when trying to connect to the database?

Comment: yes, provided TCP ip is enabled for the SQL Server and that you use the correct port. Keep in mind that you should never use SA outside of testing. Its best to setup another account with less privileges. You can test on your host machine by connecting against the IP first. if that works try from remote.

Comment: @M.Scherzer Thanks for your help!  I'll try these steps that you have suggested.  I'll be sure to ensure that TCP/IP has been enabled, I'll try the SA account, and I'll use SSMS to access the database.  Thanks, again!

Comment: @M.Scherzer Just wanted to thank you again!  Your advice and tips helped me to solve this issue.  I was able to start the ad hoc network and connect to it and the database with a remote laptop.  I didn't use the SA account.  Instead, I created a user specifically for this purpose.  Once I mapped the user and set the roles, I was able to easily connect via sqlcmd, SSMS, and connection string within a C# program.  Thank you so much!